# If I'm a sophomore in high school, what Year would I be?

Tags: meaning, phrase-requests

I'm trying to sign up for UCAS, but I don't know what to put for the Year (Year One, Year Two, all through to "Post 19".) What do you call the years for high school students?

Comment: http://www.free-for-kids.com/uk-us-education-systems.shtml.  You could really improve this question by editing to tell where you are (I guess US) and where you are applying (I guess UK).

Comment: UCAS is a UK organisation, but the term "sophomore" is not generally used in the UK.

Comment: Also, the term "high school" is not used in the UK.

Comment: "High School" is used in Scotland, but in the rest of the UK, it's 'secondary school'.

Comment: The OP is a sophomore and trying to express the equivalent in the UK. The table from @cobaltduck looks like a great resource.

Comment: @MετάEd Well then she should have asked the appropriate education authority.

Answer (score 3):

In the US the grades are "preschool" and "kindergarten", prior to the start of the numbered grades.  Then "elementary school", consisting of "first grade" (at about age 6) through "sixth grade".

Next are "seventh" and "eighth" in "junior high school", then "ninth" through "twelfth" in "high school".  The high school grades are also referred to as "freshman" (ninth), "sophomore" (tenth), "junior" (eleventh), and "senior" (twelfth).  This makes most "on schedule" graduating seniors be at or near their 18th birthday on graduation.

Often the grades 6-9 are grouped differently, with, eg, 6-8 or 7-9 in "middle school" or some such.  (This does not affect the freshman=ninth, senior=twelfth association.)

But keep in mind that there are only limited nationwide rules and standards for US primary and secondary education, and some localities may use a radically different system.  (Though, for practical reasons it's likely they will all offer some equivalent of a high school diploma for those satisfactorily completing the equivalent of 12 years of primary and secondary education.)

(In college/university the patterns are less well-defined, but traditionally the freshman-senior progression corresponds to the first through fourth years of a standard 4-year baccalaureate program.  But these days this gets muddied, with some students graduating in 3 years and other in 7, so the terms are not used much except perhaps at "ivy league" schools.)

Comment: +1  not sure what anyone saw to downvote this answer but here’s my upvote.

Comment: Several U.S. colleges and universities now define the terms freshman, sophomore, junior, and senior not by time but by accumulated credit hours, i.e Freshman = 0 to 25, Sophomore = 26 to 55, etc..  In a few cases, anyone with enough credit hours for graduation but who has not completed all requisites is a "super senior."